# selenium based python function correctly locally fails on hosted?

Tags: python, selenium, heroku

I made a python script using selenium to join my daily zoom meeting and keep records of participants which it send me on telegram.

the scripts works perfectly on local machine and on heroku when hosted.

Today I edited to script locally to join audio by computer and mute itself it works fine locally but when hosted it does join by computer but does not unmute heroku is not allowing chrome to connect to audio...

can anyone suggest a fix to this.

[image: Here is image of what is happening]

BTW its my 1st my 1st day 1st question on stackoverflow so forgive me for mistakes.

Comment: What is the error your are getting?

Comment: my bot is unable to join zoom meeting audio by computer see the image i posted ..it will help understand my issue.

Comment: basically i want heroku app to allow chrome to connect to mic...i saw various things regarding this like on how on discord they use ffmpeg opus discord voice and all..but what to do  on selenium based chrome... i just mic and speaker access on heroku that's all....maybe some buildpack or dependency will solve this issue...but i'm new to heroku so pls suggest something.